# Cannot add plugins to QGIS on Ubuntu 11.10 Oneric

Tags: qgis, plugins, ubuntu

I have installed Qgis on ubuntu. it works fine but I am not getting option to add new plugins only option to manage plugins is available. Please help

Comment: No Fetch Python Plugins option?

Comment: Is there a "Python Console" entry in Plugins menu?

Comment: I'm having the same problem with Sabayon-Linux...

Answer (score 10):

**UPDATE:**

Did some digging around on the QGIS site. Apparently you need to [install the python-gis package](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/Download#Ubuntu-With-updated-dependencies) if you want to use the python plugins.

```
sudo apt-get install python-qgis
```

You should now be able to add new plugins :)

<s>If I'm not mistaken, you need to enable the Plugins Installer. Just activate it in Plugins Manager.</s>

Answer (score 4):

This problem also occurs while moving from QGIS 2.2 to the 2.6 under Ubuntu 14.04
and is also solved by installing (or re installing) the package `python-qgis`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu 11.10 (oneiric).  To get the python plugin installer back, I uninstalled all qgis packages, added the unstable ubuntu-gis repositories (https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntugis-unstable):

deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu oneiric main

deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu oneiric main

and then reinstalled qgis.  Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

This can also happen if you start QGIS from a Python virtual environment shell.

I had a previously perfectly working QGIS+Python system suddenly stop doing Python. Nothing had changed or upgraded. It was literally working ten minutes ago. Then it wasn't.

Turned out I'd started it from a Python virtual environment, so the python libs needed weren't there. Opened a fresh shell, started QGIS, Python working nicely.

I still occasionally start QGIS from a virtual environment and go "oops".