# Fetch Python Plugins missing

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, ubuntu, qgis-1

I'm running QGis master v1.9.0 on xubuntu and the 'fetch python plugins' option is absent. [This guy](http://qgismalaysia.blogspot.ie/2013/04/ubuntu-1304-and-qgis.html) had this problem with vanilla 1.7.5 but fixed it by upgrading to 1.9.0 master. [Nishant](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20865/cannot-add-plugins-to-qgis-on-ubuntu-11-10-oneric) had this problem (version unknown); not sure if he fixed it but of the two solutions posted, the first (sudo apt-get install python-qgis) is already installed, and the second (uninstall, reboot, reinstall) changed nothing.

Any ideas?

Arguably irrelevant but actually not: is there somewhere we can find the estimated landing date for QGis 2.0? If it's due tomorrow, for example, there's little point trying to debug a problem in the 1.9 master only for all such problems to be eradicated with the fresh 2.0 install... :)

Thanks!!

Comment: Also there isn't a release date for 2.0 yet.

Comment: 10.1 does not have a fetch python polygon how do I asses it???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The plugin manager and installer have been merged into a single tool now

[image]

Comment: Aha, I suspected that this might be the case. In which case, I'll open another bug request for my problem. Cheers!

Comment: Which problem is that?

Comment: I was going to post it but you've found it & answered it already. You're like the Roadrunner of qgis help! :)